# MS SQL Join based on One conditional if NULL, two if value passed

Tags: sql-server, conditional-statements, inner-join

We have an SMS Text Message sender for various merchants that sends text messages based on the merchant ID. They can also send SMS Messages to limiting them to the Location ID.

When the SMS Campaign is set, the Merchant ID (MID) will be set, but the Location ID (LID) will be NULL unless the user wants to limit the SMS campaign to only those that have visited a specific location.

Here's my attempt:

```
SELECT * FROM tblOrders_SMS
INNER JOIN tblMerchants ON sms_order_mid = merchant_mid
(
CASE 
WHEN ISNULL(sms_order_lid,1)
INNER JOIN tblLookup_Locations_Members ON lm_mid = sms_order_mid
ELSE
INNER JOIN tblLookup_Locations_Members ON lm_mid = sms_order_mid AND lm_lid =  sms_order_lid
END
)
INNER JOIN tlbMembers ON member_id = lm_member_id
WHERE sms_order_sent = 0
```

So the idea is do an inner join on just the MID fields if the sms_order_lid is NULL, but if the SMS Campaign order has a LID set in sms_order_lid, then make it join on both fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ISNULL is a function and replaces a null value if the value in the column is null. 
Almost exactly like COALESCE in ANSI-Standard-SQL 
It's not an if clause.

Second, if you want to catch NULL in a "case when" clause in T-SQL, your syntax

```
CASE 
WHEN ISNULL(sms_order_lid,1)
...
```

is wrong, and this syntax is right:

```
CASE 
WHEN sms_order_lid IS NULL THEN [...]
ELSE [...]
END
```

Third, unless I interpreted your ISNULL wrong, this is what you actually want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblOrders_SMS 

INNER JOIN tblMerchants 
    ON sms_order_mid = merchant_mid

INNER JOIN tblLookup_Locations_Members 
     ON lm_mid = sms_order_mid 
     AND 
     (
         lm_lid =  sms_order_lid
         OR 
         sms_order_lid IS NULL 
     )

INNER JOIN tlbMembers 
      ON member_id = lm_member_id 

WHERE sms_order_sent = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tblOrders_SMS
        INNER JOIN
        tblMerchants ON sms_order_mid = merchant_mid
        INNER JOIN
        tblLookup_Locations_Members ON
                (sms_order_lid IS NULL AND lm_mid = sms_order_mid) OR
                (lm_mid = sms_order_mid AND lm_lid =  sms_order_lid)
        INNER JOIN
        tlbMembers ON member_id = lm_member_id
WHERE   sms_order_sent = 0
```